# Claiming Super Bitcoin (SBTC) with Ledger Nano S?

Tags: blockchain-fork, ledger-hardware-wallet

Quick look at CoinMarketCap: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/super-bitcoin/

*(it was airdropped in 1-to-10 proportion)*

Some scammy discussion: https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/sbtc/post/p_409993

*(put your 24 words seed and be scammed)*

Really unsure if there is any way of claiming SBTC without the aid of Ledger developers.

Or maybe there is a legitimate way to use 24 words seed, and therefore get access to SBTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Walleting services

- https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2434261.0
- https://dig.walleting.services/#/

> Select Electrum, BIP39 (Trezor/Ledger), or WIF Private Key. For BIP39 or WIF, select the appropriate SegWit options. Ledger / Trezor Help

#### Some informational websites

- http://www.findmycoins.ninja/ - tells you which forks do you have
- https://bitcoinforks.io/

#### Guides

- https://99bitcoins.com/how-to-claim-bitcoin-forks-guide/
- https://steemit.com/bitcoin/@pieczywo/how-to-extract-multiple-bitcoin-forks-easiest-and-fastest-way

#### Security disclaimer:

Always send the coins to the address you control first.

Don't trust 3rd party software with your private keys.

> EMPTY YOUR WALLET! Seeds & private keys give us FULL ACCESS to your funds!